# Сложение символов в Java

Tags: java, потоки-данных, char, печать

Есть задача на счастливый билетик. Получаем на вход строку `"123456"` (строка содержит 6 целых цифр) и выводим `"Счастливый"` если сумма трёх первых и трех последующих чисел равны, иначе `"Обычный билетик"` (допустим).

2. На ум приходит мысль о преобразовании строки в массив символов и последующее преобразование содержимого массива в целочисленную переменную, ну и произвести сложение в нужном порядке. Это работает, всё отлично.
3. Есть более изящное для этого случая решение, это всего лишь перевести строку в массив символов и сложить символы в соответствии с таблицей системы Windows:
   0 - 48
   1 - 49
   2 - 50
   3 - 51
   4 - 52
   5 - 53
   6 - 54
   7 - 55
   8 - 56
   9 - 57

Вот собственно рабочий код:

```
    var scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
    String number = scan.next();
    char[] ch = number.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(ch[0] + ch[1] + ch[2]);
    System.out.println(ch[3] + ch[4] + ch[5]);
    System.out.println(ch[0] + ch[1] + ch[2] == ch[3] + ch[4] + ch[5] ? "Lucky" : "Regular");
```

Как это работает: получаем строку `"090234"`, складываем десятичные коды символов `48 + 57 + 48 = 153` 
`50 + 51 + 52 = 153`. Вроде как для этой задачи всё гладко и понятно. Но теперь самое интересное, почему когда я вывожу результат сложение символов через принт, то он даст результат рассчитанный выше, но если вывести цифру, например `'6'` результат будет `6`? Вот пример:

```
System.out.print('2' + '3'); // 101
System.out.print('6');       // 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что при сложении 2-х `char` результат автоматически преобразуются в `int` ,чтобы избежать переполнения.
В первом случае при сложении `char` преобразуется в `int` и соответственно печатается число.
Во втором случае это константа типа `char` - она и печатается.
Так же стоит добавить что `char` является целочисленным типом

Answer (score 1):

При сложении символы переводятся в соответствие с таблицей кодировки, чтобы не возникала переполнения, и выводится результат, соответственно, по таблице

```
System.out.print('2' + '3'); // 101
```

Если вам надо получить символ, то можете использовать явное преобразование типов

```
System.out.println((char)('2'+'3')); // e
```

Но надо учитывать, что выведется символ соответствующий цифровому представлению в кодировке, то есть '2' + '3' = 101 = e, а НЕ '2' + '3' = '5'.

Когда же вам надо вывести отдельный символ, то он выведется просто как символ, не переводясь в кодировку

```
System.out.print('6');       // 6
```

Если же вам надо вывести код одного символа, то так же можно использовать явное преобразование

```
System.out.println((int)'6'); // 54
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я сегодня утром проснулся и понял ответ на свой вопрос. Но было уже поздно - вопрос я уже задал, надеюсь данный ответ поможет другим людям.